# Validation error during model generation in one-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I run application I have this error:

> PossibleAnswer_Question_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role
>   'PossibleAnswer_Question_Source' in relationship
>   'PossibleAnswer_Question'. Because the Dependent Role properties are
>   not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.

How to resolve it?

Model classes for `Question` and `PossibleAnswer`:

```
public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociatedWithProfessor { get; set; }
        public bool IsAssociatedWithAssistant { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
    }
public class PossibleAnswer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("QuestionID")]
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
```

And I put this in `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PossibleAnswer>()
               .HasRequired(f => f.Question)
               .WithRequiredDependent()
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Try add `[Key]` attribute to `Question.ID` property, or add `[InverseProperty("ID")]` to `PossibleAnswer.Question`

Comment: After that I get this: The property 'ID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you defined 1:1 relationship in your fluent mapping, so follow answer from @octavioccl... And of course, the inverse property should be `[InverseProperty("PossibleAnswers ")]`, but it is not required when you fix the mapping and add `[Key]` attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not configuring a one-to-many relationship in the `OnModelCreating` method (that is a one-to-one configuration). To achieve what you want, you could do this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PossibleAnswer>()
           .HasRequired(pa => pa.Question)
           .WithMany(q=>q.PossibleAnswers)
           .HasForeignKey(pa=>pa.QuestionID)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This way, you don't need to use the `ForeignKey` attribute on the `Question` navigation property. Is a good practice try to not merge Fluent Api with Data Annotations